# Как убрать выпуклость у кнопки на мобильных устройствах?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, button, веб-дизайн

На десктопе кнопка плоская и цвет более насыщенный, а на мобильных устройствах отображается совсем иначе. Как это исправить ?

```css
.but{
    width: 8em;
    height: 3em;
    background: #5AC8FA;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius:  30px; 
    -webkit-border-radius:  30px; 
    border: none;
    font-family: 'ProductSans-Regular';
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="but" onclick="Score()" value="Проверить" style="font-size: 1em;">
```

[image: button]

Comment: Можно попробовать скинуть все настройки input'a: input type="button" {all: unset}. Или сбросить браузерные настройки кнопки: {-webkit-appearance: none}.

Comment: @NeedHate в первом случае кнопка исчезает в принципе, во втором убираются вообще все применённые к ней стили :(

Comment: Это свойство нужно ставить перед всеми стилями, не в конце: это обнуляет заданные браузером стили.

Comment: @NeedHate заработало, спасибо большое!